# phpmyadmin loaded index but shows total blank and the firebug console indicates that "$ is not defined"

Tags: jquery, phpmyadmin, xampp

1. I installed xampp in win7 and phpMyAdmin worked very well before.
2. But some operations could not be excuted suddenly and firebug showed that
   `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. And IE is same with firefox.
3. ***127.0.0.1*** still works fine.
4. I searched a lot but could not find out the problems. So reinstall
   firefox and xampp, but **got a blank page in
   *127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin***.
5. The firebug shows that the request below is failed.

> **GET get_scripts.js.php?token.............**

It seems like that the request is fail to load jquery src js file to make the blank page happened. Could you tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: $ is not defined just means that jQuery has not be loaded. Try to hardcode it in and check again. If need be - check with the google hosted version: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Really thanks for your replying. Could you tell me how to hardcode it? Thanks very much.

Comment: Add the following code inside "<head></head>" and before other javascript code:
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I Change all js of this request into real path and get the login page. After login another request(get_imag.js.php) goes wrong like this one(get_script.js.php). I think when post request to phpmyadmin/js/get_scripts.js.php and /phpmyadmin/js/get_imge.js.php, they do not return a response.

Comment: so I still could not do anything on this page.

Comment: How are you requesting the php files?

Comment: I did not change anything, but it fixed by itself. Acuturally, I do update microsoft office. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

What I finally deduced (after digging through many many posts) is that some of the PhpMyAdmin files the header & script tags load text/javascript when they should be application/javascript (new standard for Html5).

So you are going to have to go into the following phpmyadmin files and change:

```
text/javascript => application/javascript
```

In theses files:

```
js/getscript.js.php
js/getimage.js.php
core.lib.php
```

And add/append (to fix the blank white page):

```
$cfg['AllowThirdPartyFraming'] = true;
```

To this file:

```
config.inc.php
```

Save and restart.

Worked for me, might for you !?

Comment: this works, also check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009091/phpmyadmin-get-scripts-js-php-and-messages-php-are-slow

Answer (score -1):

Go to your phpmyadmin instalation folder and run:

```
yarn install --production
```

Answer (score -2):

[Here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11596) is the resolution fixed for me.

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    listen 80;

    server_name phpmyadmin.dev;

    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;

    access_log off;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ ^/(.+\.php)$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_buffers 8 512k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 5m;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 5m;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 5m;
    }
}
```