# phpMyAdmin get_scripts.js.php and messages.php are slow

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I inspect the network activity on 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin I see that get_scripts.js.php and messages.php are taking 7 to 16 seconds to execute

I opened these scripts and added the cache time but the problem persists

```
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 3600 * 24) . ' GMT');
```

Is there some setting I should change or do I have to modify the files and implement some kind of filesystem caching ?

Comment: I managed to implement filesystem caching and now it's only taking 700ms to execute http://pastebin.com/3MZsjwHJ